# Send JSON DATA as POST using CURL functions

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I trying to finish this functions, (WORDPRESS WOOCOMMERCE ORDERS EXPORT TO JSON FORMAT AND SEND AS POST) I got now my JSON DATA, but isn't like that i need. I get the JSON IN 2 LINES 
[JSON DATA....] [JSON DATA2...] But i need like this [JSON DATA, JSON DATA2, JSON DATA3....]

How i generated this output... 

**The query and code**

```
<?php 
    //query
            global $woocommerce; 
            global $wpdb; 
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
                'orderby' => 'ID',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array('processing'))));
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id); 
            $items = $order->get_items(); ?>
```

And the $json = array(.... contents) is here

```
    <?php
        //Colecting all the datas in array
        // All the information of the customer
        $json_full = array();
        $json=array(
        "salutation"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_titel'][0] .'' ,
        "title"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_anrede'][0] .'',
        "first_name"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_first_name'][0] .'',
        "last_name"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_last_name'][0] .'',
        "street"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_1'][0] .'',
        "street_number"=>''.$order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_2'][0] .'',
        "address_supplement"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_company'][0] .'',
        "zipcode"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_postcode'][0] .'',
        "city"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_city'][0] .'',
        "country"=>''.$pais.'',
        "terms_accepted"=>true,   
        "receiving_mails_accepted"=>$email,   
        "email"=>''. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0] .'',
        "lottery_accepted"=> false,
        "lottery_solution"=> "LOTTERY",
        "original_created_at"=>''.date( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ).'',
       );
        // $json = array_map('htmlentities',$json);
         //$json = html_entity_decode(json_format($json));
         //Getting order name and quantity
           // $productmeta = new WC_Product($id);
            //$sku = $productmeta->post->sku;
         foreach($items as $item) 
               {
               $sku = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare('SELECT meta_value FROM dsr_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_sku"                            AND post_id='.$item['product_id'].''));
              $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
              $camp = $sku_s[1];
              $itm_n = $sku_s[0];
              $json['items'][] = array (
                 "campaign_number"=>(int)$camp,
                 "item_number" =>(int)$itm_n, // Here appear the name of the product
                 //'item_number' => $item['qty']); // here the quantity of the product
              );}array_push($json_full, $json);?>
```

**My ouput**

```
[{"salutation":"Prof","title":"herr","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Schumacher","street":"Insekammer","street_number":"2","address_supplement":"Media","zipcode":"81569","city":"Munich","country":"Deutschland","terms_accepted":true,"receiving_mails_accepted":true,"email":"schuma@cher.com","lottery_accepted":false,"lottery_solution":"LOTTERY","original_created_at":"2014-01-16T23:13:12","items":[{"campaign_number":66,"item_number":481}]}]

[{"salutation":"Dr.","title":"herr","first_name":"Julia","last_name":"G\u00f3mez","street":"c\/ luis cernudatte","street_number":"1","address_supplement":"Internauticos","zipcode":"SALTERAS","city":"Sevilla","country":"Spanien","terms_accepted":true,"receiving_mails_accepted":true,"email":"mein@domain.com","lottery_accepted":false,"lottery_solution":"LOTTERY","original_created_at":"2014-01-07T12:42:50","items":[{"campaign_number":66,"item_number":481}]}]
```

**But, really i need  is**

```
Like this example

[
    {
        "salutation": "Herr",
        "title": "Prof.",
        "first_name": "Max",
        "last_name": "Schulz",
        "street": "Geranienweg",
        "street_number": "11",
        "address_supplement": "Robinienstr. 23",
        "zipcode": "47509",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "terms_accepted": true,
        "receiving_mails_accepted": false,
        "email": "example@domain.com",
        "lottery_accepted": false,
        "lottery_solution": "LOTTERY",
        "original_created_at": "2013-10-30T18:10:28+01:00",
        "items": [
            {
                "campaign_number": 393,
                "item_number": 2
            },
            {
                "campaign_number": 394,
                "item_number": 5
            }
        ]
    }, <---! here continuation of another order.
    {
        "salutation": "Herr",
        "first_name": "Frank",
        "street_number": "11",
        "zipcode": "47509",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "terms_accepted": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "campaign_number": 393,
                "item_number": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]<- here the end of the ALL orders.
```

**My code for send as post to the server, i don't know if is correct, but the response of the server is**

```
  <?php 
$url = "url";
        $content = json_encode($json_full);
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array("Content-type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ( $status != 201 ) {
            die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode ?>
```

**In my ouput i got like in blocks, i think this is because the loop or while of wordpress I would appreciate your help**

Answer (score 0):

Make a new variables $json = array() and set for each value $json[] = array( [values] ).
Don't use array_push.

Comment: Can you explain pleaseeee :)

Comment: $json[] = array("first_name" => "Max", "last_name" => "Schulz");
$json[] = array("first_name" => "John", "last_name" => "Schulz");

and so on...